# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject

Tags: java, json, servlets

I am using Eclipse IDE and am writing a servlet. The servlet should accept values from an html file and return JSON response accordingly.

My doPost() is:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try
        {
        res.setContentType("application/json");
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "nocache");
            res.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        String un=req.getParameter("uname");
        String pw=req.getParameter("password");

        if(un.equals("xxx") && pw.equals("xxx"))            
            json.put("result", "success");
        else
            json.put("result", "fail");

        out.print(json.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e){System.out.print( e.getMessage());}  
    }
```

When I run this servlet in Eclipse I get a file download dialog.

When run outside Eclipse with Tomcat, I get error:

```
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
    Server1.doPost(Server1.java:25)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    Server1.doPost(Server1.java:25)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

The line Server1.doPost(Server1.java:25) refers to

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
```

I have added the org.json.jar to the build path as well as added it to deployment path in `Properties->Configure build path->Deployment assembly`

Comment: Hope the below links helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657585/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-json-simple-parser-parseexception-with-eclip

Comment: Just check whether your library (org.json.jar) is generated in the deployment location. As per your comments you have added the required jar in your classpath and deployment assembly So it should be generated in the deployment location. Is it available in deployment location ?

Comment: Please provide more details on how do you run your application in Tomcat. For example, if you export a WAR from Eclipse and deploy it manually in Tomcat, then you should check if the JARs are being exported correctly to the /lib folder within the WAR.

Comment: @sankar I had referred your suggested link and did the deployment path addition but that does not silve my problem

Comment: @JayaAnanthram I checked the deployment location n it is available there

Comment: @AJPerez I put the .class file in classes folder of web-inf,edited the web.xml,restarted tomcat and gave the URL of html in browser.

Comment: What is the exact jar name? and What is the import statement that you have given for the JSONObject?

Comment: Then you have to copy the JAR to WEB-INF/lib within your webapp in Tomcat. It doesn't matter that you already configured it in Eclipse, Tomcat doesn't know...

Comment: @JayaAnanthram The import statement is import org.json.JSONObject; and jar name is org.json-20120521.jar

Comment: Are you sure? Did you verified whether org.json-20120521.jar is available in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: @Jaya Ananthram  I seemed to have mistaken the deployment location.I added it now. Thank you!

Comment: @AJPerez  I added the jar to WEB-INF/lib and it worked as expected. Thank you!

Comment: But why can't I run it in Eclipse?

Comment: Try by **clean and build** and then run your project. For Eclipse, adding a class path variable is enough to avoid class reference error in eclipse. Only if you add your library in your deployment assembly, library will be available on run time (jar will be moved to your lib)

Comment: @JayaAnanthram Still no luck!

Comment: Did you redeployed (publish) your application?

Comment: @JayaAnanthram Well I did clean build and restarted server and run the servlet. Should any other steps be followed?

Comment: @vaishnavee Did you added in deployment assembly of your war or some other project which is added as project reference to the WAR?

Comment: @JayaAnanthram I added it to my war

Comment: Then it must work !!! There is no chance of flaws !!! Tried?

Comment: @JayaAnanthram Ya it should work, I guess I will have to run it w/o IDE afterall :(

Comment: Nope It should work.. How you are adding the jar in classpath and deployment assembly. Just give me simple comments.

Comment: I added the jar file in classpath by editing variable in environment variables. gave path of jar file located on my desktop.

Comment: and as I mentioned I added it in deployment assembly by giving the path of WEB-INF/lib/org.json-20120521.jar of eclipse project

Comment: **I added the jar file in classpath by editing variable in environment variables.** Do you mean about MyComputer(right click)->Properties->Advanced Settings->Environment variable?

Comment: Refer my answer below.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**No.. It is not proper way.** Refer the steps,

`For Classpath reference:` Right click on project in Eclipse -> Buildpath -> Configure Build path -> Java Build Path (left Pane) -> Libraries(Tab) -> Add External Jars -> Select your jar and select OK.

`For Deployment Assembly:` Right click on WAR in eclipse-> Buildpath -> Configure Build path -> Deployment Assembly (left Pane) -> Add -> External file system -> Add -> Select your jar -> Add -> Finish.

This is the proper way!  Don't forget to remove environment variable. It is not required now.

Try this. Surely it will work. Try to use Maven, it will simplify you task.

Comment: Where is the WAR when you mention "Right-click on WAR" in Eclipse?

Answer (score 36):

Please add the following dependency 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20080701

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20080701</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Exception it self says it all `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject`

You have not added the necessary jar file which will be having `org.json.JSONObject` class to your `classpath`.

You can [Download it From Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm)

Answer (score -1):

Add **json jar** to your classpath

or use `java -classpath json.jar ClassName`

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362302/java-servlet-error-with-jsonobject)

Comment: I added the jar file in classpath by editing it in environment variables. That's the way to do it , right?