# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject when Java Class runs on OAM Server

Tags: java, json, oracle, manifest

I'm getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject` when i'm running my `.class` on **Oracle Access Manager**

This is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
at phillplugin.PhillPlugin.process(PhillPlugin.java:118)
```

> **`PhillPlugin.java:118`** contains just a creation of an instance of a `JSONObject`

```java
//Line 118:
 JSONObject x = new JSONObject();
```

I'm using **JDeveloper IDE** and i have included the `org.json.jar` in my ***Libraries*** and in my ***Deployment*** profile

> Note that when i'm executing it from a simple `main.class` it runs perfectly

I have to include the `org.json.jar` in the MANIFEST.MF file of the deploying `PhillPlugin.jar` and i have done it as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Version: 10
Bundle-Name: PhillPlugin
Bundle-Activator: phillplugin.PhillPlugin
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Import-Package: 
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
 oracle.security.am.plugin,
 oracle.security.am.plugin.authn,
 oracle.security.am.plugin.impl,
 oracle.security.am.plugin.api,
 oracle.security.am.common.utilities.principal,
 oracle.security.idm,
 javax.security.auth,
 org.json.JSONObject;resolution:=optional,
 org.json.JSONArray;resolution:=optional,
 org.json;resolution:=optional
Export-Package: 
 org.json.JSONObject;resolution:=optional,
 org.json.JSONArray;resolution:=optional,
 org.json;resolution:=optional
Bundle-SymbolicName: PhillPlugin
Bundle-ClassPath: org.json.jar,utilities.jar,oam-plugin.jar,felix.jar,identity-provider.jar
```

But still the server **does not recognise my imports**

Let me mention that the `PhillPlugin.jar` contains:

- `MANIFEST.MF`
- `PhillPlugin.class` - line 118 gives me the error only on the server
- `PhillPlugin.xml`

I will be happy to provide you with any other extra information you need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504508/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-json-jsonobject)

Comment: i've seen it, it's different for OAM server, i need to refer to it through my `manifest.mf` file, just by including it on my project won't fix the problem.

Comment: By the looks of it, you should list package names, but instead you are also listing class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to include the external library in both `MANIFEST.MF`(reference) as i correctly did, and  also the `org.json.jar` in the final `PhillPlugin.jar` as well as the `json` libraries
This way the server was able to see my imports

Here is the sample that worked for me:
[image]

> Note that, the exception was being triggered even if the `org` folder was missing or the `org.json.jar` was missing